# EntityFremework: could a select before a where optimize this?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, query-optimization

I'm trying to gain performance on this query, and I'd like to know if calling a Select() before the Where() I could have some improvement:

```
 public async Task<List<PostValues>> GetValuesToTheDashboard(DataFilter filter, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
                long startTimestanp = Helpers.UnixTimeNow(filter.StartDate);
                long endTimestanp = Helpers.UnixTimeNow(filter.EndDate);

                return await
                    _context.CatchDetails.Where(
                        x => x.Monitoring.Client.Id == filter.CustomerId && x.Data.published >= startTimestanp
                             && x.Data.published <= endTimestanp
                             && ((filter.Sentiment == Sentiments.ALL) || x.Sentiment_enum == filter.Sentiment)
                             && (filter.MonitoringId == 0 || x.Monitoring.id == filter.MonitoringId)
                             && (filter.KeywordId == 0 || x.Keyword.Id == filter.KeywordId)
                             && (filter.MotiveId == 0 || x.Motive.Id == filter.MotiveId)
                             && (filter.SocialNetwork.Count == 0 || filter.SocialNetwork.Any(s => x.Data.social_media == s))
                             && (filter.Busca == "" || x.Data.content_snippet.Contains(filter.Busca))
                             && (filter.Gender.Count == 0 || filter.Gender.Any(g => x.Data.extra_author_attributes.gender_enum == g)))
                             .Select(s => new PostValues() {
                                 CatchDetailsId=s.Id,
                                 Monitoring=s.Monitoring.name,
                                 Keyword=s.Keyword.Text,
                                 Motive=s.Motive.Name,
                                 Sentiment=s.Sentiment_enum,
                                 Gender=s.Data.extra_author_attributes.gender_enum,
                                 SocialMedia=s.Data.social_media,
                                 Country=s.Data.extra_author_attributes.world_data.country_code,
                                 State=s.Data.extra_author_attributes.world_data.region,
                                 Published=s.Data.published

                             }).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
```

Comment: Select before where would not make any difference as the final query execution happens when `ToListAsync` happens. And the generated query for database will be the same for both before and after select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a way how to improve performance, but it won't be with switching `Select` and `Where` (as Chetan mentioned in the comment).

You could build the query in a sequence and based on the filter get a simpler query in the end. This would go like this:

```
var query = _context.CatchDetails.Where(
                x => x.Monitoring.Client.Id == filter.CustomerId && x.Data.published >= startTimestanp
                     && x.Data.published <= endTimestanp);
if (filter.Sentiment != Sentiments.ALL) 
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Sentiment_enum == filter.Sentiment);
}
if (filter.MonitoringId != 0)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Monitoring.id == filter.MonitoringId);
}

[...]

return await 
    query.Select(s => new PostValues() {
        [...]
        }).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Doubt this will do anything, as `'blah'='blah'` in SQL is trivial, and likely to be optimised by the execution plan anyway.

Comment: @NPras: for the most simple ones you are right; but it might simplify the tree for the optimizer if you can get rid of some joins in the where clause.

Comment: Ah yeah true. Those joins are gonna be the pain points in this whole thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I still had not realized that I could compose the query in this way before executing.
It helped a lot :D

Comment: @NPras EF translates queries with non-constant expressions into parameters.  So it's not `'blah' = 'blah`, it's `@pBlah = 'blah'`. And SQL Server will create a reusable plan for the parameterized query.  Which means it has to select a query plan that works for every value of the parameter.

Comment: Ah interesting. I just assumed (wrongly) that the variables at the time of execution were captured and used as part of the generated SQL. Guess it makes more sense this way if it's meant to be reusable.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget, the variable `query` is already on memory of the application when the SQL returns data. If there is many results it could throw memory exception.

I suggest that you limit the range of date on that search.